# small portion of my making my html website- I have a javascript section

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need help on a small javascript portion of my website assignment for class, filling in the blanks:
In the script section of your contact.html page, inside your document ready function but outside your submit function) add the following code to turn the dialog div (above) into a jQuery dialog box.

```
$(_______).dialog({
         autoOpen: _____________,
         modal: ________,
         width: ________,
         buttons: {
          "_______": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                     } 
        }
});
```

Note, this is just the code you are given in the demos for creating a dialog box.  I have added several blanks to the code that you will need to set as follows:
The dialog function needs to be called for the element with the id of dialog.
It should not auto open
It should be modal
It should have a width set that is less than 600 pixels
The button name should be OK or Accept  or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this not the right forum to ask these kind of questions, here is the answer for your question.

```
$("#DivIdWhichWillBecomeADialog").dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false, 
    modal: true, 
    width: 500px, 
    buttons: { 
        "OK": function() { 
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
              } 
    } 
});
```

Comment: @basicavocado Accept the answer, if this is what you meant.

Comment: When writing javascript and jquery can I make functions for any of my div id's by just putting the div id in the spot where you wrote "DivIdWhichWillBecomeADialog" like "#dialog"  sorry i'm a beginner, these are probably dumb questions. and what does modal mean in this sense?

Comment: For first question, yes. Modal means the dialog blocks the page. You cannot operate on the page until you close the dialog. But if modal property is set to false, the dialog doesn't block the page. And it's a part of jQuery Ui.Visit this site for more details. https://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog({ 
        autoOpen: false, 
        modal: true, 
        width: 500px, 
        buttons: { 
            "OK": function() { 
                    $(this).dialog("close"); 
                  } 
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer:

```
$(function() {
   $("#dialogDivId" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false, 
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
         Ok: function() {
         $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      width:550
   });
});
```